# Spring AOP: a proxy per advice?

Tags: java, spring, proxy, aop

I've read that Spring typically creates only one proxy per target even if multiple advices are applied to it ( http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?23980-AOP-TechMap-1-proxy-per-advice&s=e077b42fd45ae3a3177a01c90339893c).

Does it mean that there are atypical situations in which Spring will create multiple proxies for a target if multiple advices are applies to it? If yes, why? and what are these situations?

Answer (score 0):

From all the documentations that I found it seems that spring indeed only creates one proxy per target (no matter how many advices are applied).

However if you add a proxy in your code using `ProxyFactory` on top of an existing proxy you might create a double proxy as far as I can understand it. and it should work...